# How to tell if Kendo Chart tooltip is currently displayed?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to prevent new data from refreshing my Kendo chart while the user is hovering over a tooltip.

My current solution is to use a `$timeout` of 5 seconds after the tooltip is drawn inside `getTooltip(e)` and using a flag to switch between `pauseUpdate` and `!pauseUpdate`.

Does Kendo provide a way to track when a tooltip gets shown on the screen and when it gets destroyed?